# Python advice with some code

Tags: python, json

I'm having some doubts with this single line of code. I´m getting a json object inside `test_data` from a webservice. Inside that json i´m searching for some things i need. The code is already written but i´m new in the team so i have to figure out what the last developer did:

```
self.has_deposit = False

self.has_deposit = 'has_deposit' in test_data.keys() and test_data['has_deposit'] is True
```

It looks very simple but i don´t get it.

Comment: Does this help: `( 'has_deposit' in test_data.keys() ) and ( test_data['has_deposit'] is True )`?

Comment: I would just do `self.has_deposit = test_data.get("has_deposit") is True` or without `is True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the expression into two parts:

```
'has_deposit' in test_data.keys()
```

This tests that the `test_data` dictionary has `'has_deposit'` key. Note that `'has_deposit' in test_data` would be another simple way to do the same thing.

This:

```
test_data['has_deposit'] is True
```

...tests that the value in that dictionary has to be `True` . The `is` operator is used so that `1` is not considered `True`.

Note: the first `has_deposit = False` line has no effect as the value is overwritten.